# Performance issue with DB2 on high latency network after move to Azure over ExpressRoute

Tags: azure, ssis, db2

Recently moved some VM's to Azure. We now have significantly higher latency to on-prem where we load data from DB2. Around 25ms over the ExpressRoute vs 1-2ms on-prem->on-prem.

We are now suffering on very low performance reading data with SSIS packages with jobs taking 6x longer than onprem->onprem. The job is a simple SELECT *  Any ideas on how to work around the higher latency? And get more troughput?

Comment: Compare the [time-spent](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=elements-time-spent-monitor-element-hierarchy#c0055434__System-levelTime-spentMonitorEleme) split at the database / connection level on both systems. If percentage of `tcpip_[recv|send]_wait_time` in `total_rqst_time` / `total_wait_time` is much higher on the same workload, then the problem is with network.
And the only way to improve the performance is to improve network latency, but it's outside of Db2 engine. But it's better to understand first, how all spent times have changed, of course...

Comment: Another indication of slow network is much higher `client_idle_wait_time`.

Comment: db2mon can show what you are waiting on, start with that.